# Find if value exists in a JSONArray in php

Tags: php, json

I have a JSONArray as shown below

```
{
    "output": [
        "a",
        "b",
        "c",
        "d",
        "e"
    ]
}
```

I need to find if "e" exists in the above array in php. Can someone help me out with this ?

Comment: what's with the downvotes?  this is a perfectly fine question from a beginner

Comment: I'm guessing it's because the asker has shown none of their own efforts in trying to solve the issue, it comes across a little like: Hey do this for me cheers bye.

Comment: well I need to know what to search inorder to find my answer. I managed to do it the C++ way of traversing through each element and finding out the value and comparing it. Just thought this would help me understand some functions in php.

Comment: @lalith Tip: Always do a simple search in the manual: http://php.net/manual-lookup.php?pattern=find+in+array, 90% of the time that answers your question.

Comment: @deceze thank you, I just found that out. I am new to PHP I dint know it had such a good manual. thank a lot guys.

Comment: it'll take several years to gain the masters mostly, took me 18 and I am still blind to a lot of it.. by the time you catch up, they release another list of syntax sugar that is beyond the scope of anything you just grasped. Time is all.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
$array = json_decode($json, true);
if (in_array('e', $array['output'])) {
    ...
}
```