# Check if 2 elements exist independently in two array with special conditions

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, filtering

I'm trying to find if a given 2-element array (`$result`) exists on a dynamically created multidimentional array.

There are 2 flat arrays (`$a` and `$b`) which will be used to generate a haystack array of 2-element combinations.

```
$a = [1, 2, 3];
$b = [3, 4, 5];

$result = [1,3];
```

I want to check if the `$result` array exists (with the two values in either orientation) in the haystack array.

The (cross joined) haystack array (`$selections`) looks like the following:

```
[
    [1,3],
    [1,4],
    [1,5],
    [2,3],
    [2,4],
    [2,5],
    [3,4],
    [3,5]
]
```

Notice that `[3,3]` is excluded by my application's logic.

I build `$selections` this way:

```
$selections = [];
foreach($a as $s){
    foreach($b as $o){
        if($s == $o){
            continue;
        }
        $selections[] = [$s, $o];
    }
}
```

The `$result` should be considered found by the following non-exhaustive list:

- `[1, 3]`
- `[3, 1]`
- `[2, 5]`
- `[3, 3]`

But pairs like these should not be considered found:

- `[1, 2]`
- `[3, 3]`
- `[4, 4]`

I tried using `array_search`(`array_search($result, $selections)`), but it only wwors if the elements are in order.

Of course, I can write a custom function to iterate through the multidimentional array and check the intersection, but I'm checking if there's a cleaner way to do this.

Comment: You don't need to generate all combinations though as it is time consuming.

Comment: See https://onecompiler.com/php/3ynecug88

Comment: Thanks for the response @nice_dev, but what about the order? let's say `$result = [3,1]`?

Comment: Can `$result` contain more/less than 2 elements? Or is it always the same number of elements as the number of input arrays?  Is it always two input arrays and always 2 elements?  Will `$result` ever contain `[3,3]` (possibly)?

Comment: `$result` always has a fixed length of 2 elements.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find if value exists in a JSONArray in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13412156/find-if-value-exists-in-a-jsonarray-in-php)

Comment: @nice, this question is clearly deeper than checking if a value is in an array.  Offering the `in_array()` function is the most sensible but it is the implementation of that function that matters -- and that dupe target in no way describes how to solve this task with that answer.

Comment: @PolSantha Thank you for clarifying the actual question later with pretty important aspects. Also, if the order doesn't matter and if the length happens to be more than 2, it would need far more work. If length just as 2, the complexity is trivial with a simple in_array.

Comment: @mickmackusa You really think adding an OR makes it different? I am assuming OP knows programming basics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To allow out of order rule satisfaction, just check both ways explicitly.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/JVuSB))

```
var_export(
    $result[0] !== $result[1] 
    && (
        (in_array($result[0], $a) && in_array($result[1], $b))
        || (in_array($result[0], $b) && in_array($result[1], $a))
    )
);
```

If the first pair of `in_array()` calls is satisfied, then the second set will not be executed at all.

Comment: I'm gonna accept this as all the test are green with this answer, but thanks all for the time and support.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to create every possible combination, it's quite expensive.

It is better to split the **$result** array and find each element in the arrays **$a and $b**.

```
<?php

$a = [1,2,3];
$b = [3,4,5];

$result = [3,1];

function isOK($a, $b, $result):bool {
    return $result[1] && in_array($result[0], $a) && in_array($result[1], $b);
}

$isOK = isOK($a, $b, $result) || isOK($a, $b, array_reverse($result));

var_dump($isOK);
```

Comment: Thanks Alexander, same question here. What about the order? let's say $result = [3,1]?

Comment: @mickmackusa yes in_array will be better

Comment: Hey Alexander, You might wanna check the answer as it's doesn't work if the order is changed in `$result` array.